# Não é possível usar tskill em C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, processo

**O comando tskill quando utilizado via C# (Visual Studio) retorna este erro:**

> 'tskill' não reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes

Entretanto o mesmo comando quando execuato via prompt de comando funciona sem qualquer problema. Imaginei que talvez isso pudesse acontecer pelo Visual Studio utilizar um diretório próprio para habilitar o acesso as linhas de comando do Windows, por isso configurei outro diretório de trablaho a ele, como pode ser visto. Entetanto, ainda assim sem sucesso.

Verifiquei que [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190287/cant-use-tskill-from-c-sharp) já foi feita, entretanto a resposta não me serve.

```
private void ClosePorts(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (@"C:\Windows\System32\");
    processStartInfo.FileName = ("cmd.exe");     
    processStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c {0}", string.Concat(@"tskill com2tcp"));
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    processStartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;    

    Process proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: por quê não executa o comando com o caminho completo? `"C:\Windows\System32\tskill com2tcp"`

Comment: Da mesma forma ele não funciona, já testei dessa forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você está tentando matar um processo, se sim porquê não fazer assim:

```
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("com2tcp"))
    process.Kill();
```

Ou, como o [Ricardo Pontual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual) sugeriu, usar direto o tskill.exe ao invés do cmd para executar o comando:

```
private void ClosePorts(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (@"C:\Windows\System32\");
    processStartInfo.FileName = "tskill.exe";     
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "com2tcp";
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    processStartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;    

    Process proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```